# Error when trying reload activity itself

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to reload an activity.
here's the code:

```
public class CobaGesture extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageButton resetBut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    resetBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)); finish();
        }
    });
```

when i press resetBut, everything is okay but i the app is kinda freezing and when i touch the screen repeatedly, the Force close i coming.
here's the logcat:

```
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103): ANR in coba.gesture (coba.gesture/.CobaGesture)
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103): Load: 3.91 / 2.13 / 1.86
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103): CPU usage from 15350ms to 0ms ago with 99% awake:
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   65% 6436/coba.gesture: 63% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 40 minor
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   29% 103/system_server: 21% user + 7.8% kernel / faults: 5 minor
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   0.9% 41/adbd: 0% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 41 minor
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   0.2% 6227/com.svox.pico: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 79 minor
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   0.1% 476/zygote: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 84 minor
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   0.4% 647/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   0.1% 225/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   0% 220/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103): 100% TOTAL: 86% user + 13% kernel + 0.1% softirq
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103): CPU usage from 3589ms to 4323ms later:
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   56% 6436/coba.gesture: 55% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 12 minor
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     27% 6446/Thread-10: 27% user + 0% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     26% 6453/Thread-11: 26% user + 0% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     1.3% 6441/Compiler: 1.3% user + 0% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   38% 103/system_server: 23% user + 14% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     19% 111/SurfaceFlinger: 11% user + 7.4% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     17% 172/InputDispatcher: 8.9% user + 8.9% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     1.4% 265/Binder Thread #: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     1.4% 268/Binder Thread #: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     1.4% 304/Binder Thread #: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     1.4% 394/Binder Thread #: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):   0.7% 647/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 1 minor
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103):     1.4% 648/HeapWorker: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
05-31 14:20:45.370: ERROR/ActivityManager(103): 100% TOTAL: 80% user + 19% kernel
```

what does it mean? how to solve it?
if you have another way to reload the activity please tell me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);` if you want to restart the activity

Comment: Why not just calling `onCreate()` to reset?

Comment: @imran i've tried it and the result is same as above.

Comment: @m0skit0 how i calling 'onCreate' ?

Comment: @m0skit0 `this.onCreate()` can't be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();

overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

I use it, and it works fine.

Comment: still "Force Close". i used it to reload the SurfaceView. it works to reload but the app is freezing and crashing down.